# How to achieve map functionality with the use of filter in JavaScript, as we can use reduce as map and filter?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, filter

Suppose I have an array `var arr = [1,2,3]` and if I do  `var result = arr.filter(callback)` I want value of `result` would be `[2,4,6]` by the use of filter. I want to only define callback function in order to do so. It can be easily done with map but I want to use only filter.

Comment: But why `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`  ? any specific reason to use `filter` here ?

Comment: Filter is not built for that..... I can open up a window with a hammer, but there are better options.

Comment: It's like trying to open up a lock using a hairpin when you've already got the key.

Comment: I know that I have map but what I need to know is that there is any way to do this or not

Comment: yes it can in a horrible way by using the arguments passed in.... but why....

Comment: it's just a curiosity question as we can use reduce as map or filter, I tried to make this happen but cann't help it

Comment: @epascarello if we can do this how can we I want to know that way

Comment: It is impossible for it to return it like map, but you can either alter the original or change another array. '

Answer (score 0):

[`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) only filters existing values in an array, effectively creating a new array that can hold the same values, their subset, or an empty array, based on the filtering function.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using `filter()`:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3];

arr.filter((c, i) => {
  arr[i] = +arr[i] * 2;
  return true;
});

console.log(arr)
```

we are always returning `true`, so `filter()` makes no sense in this case.

Comment: Ok, I already try this but it does not work if I want to use it like `[1, 2, 3].filter(callback);`

Comment: I mean if I did not have a array stored in variable before using filter

Comment: @Abhishek-Saini I think is not possible in a way like `[1, 2, 3].filter(callback);` since we can't return a value.

Answer (score 0):

As stated many times, there is no reason why you should do it.

It is impossible to do it like map because map returns a new array. You can either alter on the original array or you have to make a clone of the original array so you do not change it.

```js
// this modifies the orginal array
var arr1 = [1,2,3]
arr1.filter((v,index,arr)=>{
  arr[index] = v * 2;
  return true
})
console.log(arr1)

// or you can clone it and do the same thing
// this modifies the cloned array
var arr2 = [1,2,3]
var arr3 = arr2.slice()
arr3.filter((v,index,arr)=>{
  arr[index] = v * 2;
  return true
})
console.log(arr2, arr3)
```

So no, you can not recreate map with filter since you HAVE to modify the original array or cheat and use a copy of the array.

Answer (score -1):

So I'm not sure I understand the second part of your question, but as for the first part:

The `callback` for `filter` has three arguments, two of which are optional.
The first argument is the current element in the traversal, and the second and third arguments (the optional ones) are the 0-based index of the current element, and a reference to the original array.
This third parameter is useful for what you're trying to do.

```js
let myArr = [1, 2, 3];

myArr.filter((el, ind, orig) => {
  orig[ind] = orig[ind] + 1; // Or, whatever map logic you want to use
  return true; // since a Boolean condition must be returned here
});
```

This way you can do it without even even having to break the scope of the function!

If you want to do it without necessarily having a variable to originally call `filter` on (you do have to pass an array), you can use the prototype and the `call` method:

```js
Array.prototype.filter.call([1, 2, 3], (el, ind, orig) => {
  orig[ind] = orig[ind] + 1;
  return true;
});
```